# How to find Object in Array which is nested as unknown times

Tags: javascript

I want to search specific "group Object" from these Array nested at unknown times. After searched, toggle that group's flag from false to true.

For searching input, in this case "searchId" is just number for groups id. And output is not modified groups Array, only searched groups flag is changed.

```
const groups = [
  {
    id: 1,
    flag: false,
    children: [
      {
        id: 4,
        flag: false,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        flag: false,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2
    flag: false,
    children: [
      {
        id: 6,
        flag: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: 7,
            flag: false,
            children: [
              {
                id: 8,
                flag: false,
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3
    flag: false,
    children: []
  },
]

const searchId = 6;

const expectedSearchResultGroups = [
  // omitting...
  {
    id: 6,
    flag: true,
    children: [
  // ...
]
```

I'd like to know how to find group.

Comment: One way to solve this is a recursive function.

Comment: [Here's one way to do it](https://pastebin.com/1vtC6xvE)